# App Engine Standard local server: NullPointerException with java 12 and maven plugin

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an java App Engine standard project and I'd like to use [maven](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-maven) to run a local server.

But I get an error I never had before:

```
mvn appengine:run
....
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFO: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\lordofmax\AppData\Local\google\ct4j-cloud-sdk\LATEST\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ja va\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Workspace\test\target\test-V1-0-0\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

My project is the hello world project from the maven [appengine-standard-archetype](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.appengine.archetypes/appengine-standard-archetype/1.0.2/maven-archetype).

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>V1-0-0</version>

  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>

  <properties>
     <app.deploy.project>lordofmax-application-test</app.deploy.project>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
    <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.76</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jstl</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
<outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

appengine-web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
    </system-properties>
</appengine-web-app>
```

My environment:

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 259.0.0
app-engine-java 1.9.76
app-engine-python 1.9.86
beta 2019.05.17
bq 2.0.46
cloud-datastore-emulator 2.1.0
core 2019.08.16
gsutil 4.42

$ mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.1 (d66c9c0b3152b2e69ee9bac180bb8fcc8e6af555; 2019-04-04T12:00:29-07:00) 
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.1 
Java version: 12.0.2, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

$ java --version
openjdk 12.0.2 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 12.0.2+10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.2+10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And I use Python 2.7.16

What can I miss in this configuration?

Comment: Ok so I tried with Java 8 and it resolves it. So I guess it's linked to the java version, although I can't find anywhere java versions > 1.8 are no supported by the plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @lordofmax in the comments, switching to Java 8 is one of the possible solutions.

The reason for this is that, according to the [Java on Google App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/), Google App Engine only supports Java 8 and 11 as Runtime Environments.